# Issue with closing login module for jasmine testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an application which uses angulars $modal to popup a login modal any time a user tried to enter a secure route without a valid authentication token. This works great but is causing an issue with my testing.

The modal was created as a factory

```
  .factory('loginModal', function ($modal) {
      return function() {
          var instance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partials/login',
            controller: 'AuthCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'AuthCtrl'
          })

        return instance.result;
      };
    });
```

In my controller I have a login action, upon successfully logging in the modal is closed using $scope.$close.

```
$scope.login = function() {
      auth.login($scope.user)
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.$close(response);
          $state.go('secure.user');
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.hasErrMsg = true;
          $scope.errMsg = 'Incorrect password.';
          $scope.$dismiss;
        });
    };
```

Lastly my unit test which is checking to make sure that auth.login is called with the correct properties when my controllers login function is called.

```
describe('Auth Controller Tests', function () {
    var $scope, $controller, $q, $httpBackend, auth, controller, deferred, loginReqHandler, userReqHandler, indexReqHandler, registerPostReqHandler, doesUserExistPostReqHandler, loginPostReqHandler, loginModal;

    beforeEach(module('enigmaApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $q = $injector.get('$q');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        auth = $injector.get('auth');
        controller = $controller('AuthCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
        deferred = $q.defer();
        spyOn(auth, 'isLoggedIn');
        loginReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'partials/login').respond(deferred.promise);
        userReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'partials/user').respond(deferred.promise);
        indexReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'partials/index').respond(deferred.promise);
        registerPostReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/register').respond(deferred.promise);
        doesUserExistPostReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/doesUserExist').respond(deferred.promise);
        loginPostReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/login').respond(deferred.promise);
        loginModal = $injector.get('loginModal');
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.flush();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
    describe('AuthCtrl.login()', function () {
        it('should call auth.login() with $scope.user', function () {
            $scope.user = {
                email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
                password: 'password123'
            };
            spyOn(auth, 'login').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
            $scope.login();
            deferred.resolve();
            $scope.$digest();
        expect(auth.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.user);
        });
    });
});
```

Now when I run the test I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $scope.$close is not a function
```

I suspect this error is because in code expects $scope to be set to the scope for the modal when it calls $scope.$close and in my test $scope is set to the controllers scope. Although I'm not sure how to reference the $modal's scope.

Update: I just discovered if I add $scope.$close = function () {}; inside the it() block then the test runs properly. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Could you show us you whole spec file please. We need to see how you are setting up your mocks etc. Better yet, create a demo on plunker. Also, I think Angular is normally meant to be tested in a synchronous manner so you shouldn't normally have to be creating deferred's.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by spec file, but I've updated my tests to show the code above the describe block. My application is async so almost every action on the controller makes an async call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably trying to test too much. If you need to be making all those `$http` calls and such just to test a controller then you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

This is how I would go about testing your controller. See comments for further explanation. I realise this might not fit you use-case exactly but hopefully you will find it helpful to see a different approach.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTLBo6vvRZhEb4iOPFPD?p=preview)

**appSpec.js**

```
describe('Auth Controller Tests', function () {

    var $scope, $controller, $state, auth, controller,
        loginDeferred, $closeSpy, goSpy, loginSpy;

    beforeEach(module('enigmaApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($q, _$controller_, _$rootScope_){

        $controller     = _$controller_;
        $scope          = _$rootScope_.$new();
        loginDeferred   = $q.defer();

        // create spies
        $closeSpy       = jasmine.createSpy('$close');  
        goSpy           = jasmine.createSpy('go');
        loginSpy        = jasmine
                          .createSpy('login')
                          .and
                          .returnValue(loginDeferred.promise);

        // create mock services with spies
        $scope.$close = $closeSpy;

        auth = {
          login   : loginSpy
        };

        $state = {
          go: goSpy
        }

        // initiate controller and inject mocks
        controller = $controller('AuthCtrl', { 
          $scope: $scope, 
          auth: auth, 
          $state: $state

        });


        // manual $digest to update our controller
        // with our mocked services and scope
        $scope.$digest();

    }));

    describe('AuthCtrl.login()', function () {

        it('should call auth.login() with $scope.user', function () {

            // define mock user object on our $scope
            $scope.user = {
                email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
                password: 'password123'
            }; 

            // call login() which in turn calls our
            //  loginSpy
            $scope.login();


            // just assert that our loginSpy was called with
            // the mockUser
            // we don't care about anything else so no need 
            // to worry about promises etc.
            expect(auth.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.user);
        });


        it('should call $state.go on succesful login', function(){
          // call login which will
          // call our authLogin spy that returns 
          // the loginDeferred promise
          $scope.login();

          // manually resolve the loginDeferred promise and 
          // call $digest to trigger the then() callback
          loginDeferred.resolve({});
          $scope.$digest();

          // assert $state.go is called when 
          // our then callback it triggered.
          expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('secure.user');
        });

        it('should set the errMsg to true if the login fails', function(){

          expect($scope.hasErrMsg).toBeUndefined();

          $scope.login();

          // this time reject our promise
          // so we can evaluate the catch callback
          loginDeferred.reject({});
          $scope.$digest();

          expect($scope.hasErrMsg).toBe(true);

        });

    });


});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('enigmaApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, auth, $state){

  // Warning: OPINIONATED CODE
  // I refactored your auth login function
  // to use the then and catch methods which I 
  // think are much cleaner
  $scope.login = function() {
      auth
        .login($scope.user)
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.$close(response);
          $state.go('secure.user');
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
          $scope.hasErrMsg = true;
          $scope.errMsg = 'Incorrect password.';
          $scope.$dismiss;
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: Okay I see where you're going here. The thing that confuses me is it seems like I should be testing the code in the auth service where this replaces that code with a mock, essentially hard coding a passing response. Are you saying that since auth.login just calls an $http request that there is no need to test the function and I just need to test that the controller calls it, or should I test the auth.login function, just in it's own test?

Comment: You should test your auth.login function but I'd recommend that you do it in a separate suite dedicated to your `auth` service. Here, in your controller test suite, you  are just asserting that the controller is calling the right services with the right arguments and the correct properties are being set on the `$scope` etc.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you never defined the spies with a var? i.e. var $closeSpy

Comment: No, that is an oversight on my part. I should have declared the variables in the top level describe block  with the others and assigned them in the `beforeEach` block. You could keep them local to the `forEach` in this case but it you might find you need to access them directly in your tests.